# mat-select not updating on selection

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select set up like this:

```
<div #3dContainer class="scene-container">
    <div id="hud">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Distance:</mat-label>
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event)" [(value)]="measuredSelected">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let measure of measured" [value]="measure">{{measure.z.toFixed(2)}} Metres</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-icon-button id="exit-btn"  (click)="closeBtnClicked()"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the method `onSelectChange()` calls into `setLatestSelection()`:

```
private setLatestSelection(firstIndex: number, secondIndex: number, distance: number, addToMeasured: boolean): void{
    let latest = new THREE.Vector3(firstIndex, secondIndex, distance);    

    if(addToMeasured){
      this.measured.push(latest);      
    }
    
    this.measuredSelected = latest;
    this.drawDistanceLine();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

So there are two routes into this method:

1. from selecting points where vector needs adding so `addToMeasured: boolean` is set to true
2. from selecting an item already in the list (measured array) so `addToMeasured: boolean` is set to false

This is so that I do not add an identical and useless item to the array. However when the array is not getting updated the selected value is not displayed. `MeasuredSelected` is set and is the value used as the selected item and is set up in the mat-select tag and it works fine when the array is updated. I already have `cdr.detectChanges()` (ChangeDetectorRef) which I thought made the system check for changes and the `MeasuredSelected` value has changed.

Basically my question is how can I force the mat-select to update its values in scenario two?

[edit]
p.s. I have tried assigning to a temp var and then assigning back but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this now and I needed to add the line `this.measuredSelected = latest;` into the if block. I am assuming that this is because I have two way binding in the html as when debugging I noticed that the value of `measuredSelected` is already set.

```
private setLatestSelection(firstIndex: number, secondIndex: number, distance: number, addToMeasured: boolean): void{
    let latest = new THREE.Vector3(firstIndex, secondIndex, distance);    

    if(addToMeasured){
      this.measured.push(latest);   
      this.measuredSelected = latest;   
    }
    
    this.drawDistanceLine();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```